# Running Logit Model on data and changing weights

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models

I have created a logit model off of my data. There are two independent variables and dependent is 0/1. If I want to run my model off of a dataset I can create probabilities from the coefficients and run it through.

What if I want to play around with the weights of the independent variables to see how the results will change? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What would you like to see the change of? Do you want to see different predictions of different models (with different weights), compare their accuracies or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The logistic regression coefficients (weights) are just the coefficients that maximize the liklihood given the data and a logistic regression model, but there is nothing holy about them and you can change them as you wish. Just be aware that changing them from the maximum likelihood values will remove the statistical properties that accompany maximim likelihood estimation (e.g., consistency, valid inference).

There are a few ways to automate the process of adjusting the coefficients as well. Ridge, lasso, and elastic net logistic regression all impose a penalty on the coefficients to shrink them closer to zero. The resulting estimates are not the maximim likelihood estimates but may have other desirable properties such as improved out-of-sample prediction accuracy. You can also move away from a logistic regression model if you want to try different models. Probit regression and other binomial regression models (e.g., with a log link, cloglog link, or identity link) may provide different estimates and model fits.

This is a bit beyond my expertise, but you could also run a Bayesian logistic regression putting different priors on the coefficients for different predictors. For example, if you know one covariate is a stronger predictor of the outcome than the other, you could encode that knowledge into the priors.